# Webpack Karma cannot resolve local import

Tags: karma-runner, webpack

I am using Webpack for both the app and tests (using https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack for it). The app is in typescript and the tests in Babel.

Importing something from a standalone module in the tests works (using `import { cleanHTML, fromHTML, toHTML } from "../../app/utils/text.ts";`, ie I need to mention the .ts extension otherwise it fails).

When I actually try to import a React component that imports a component in another file, I get the following error:
`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./blocks/paragraph`.

The tree of directory looks like:

```
src/
  app/
    components/
      blocks/
        paragraph.ts
    main.ts
  tests/
    components/
       main_tests.js
    utils/
```

And the main.ts imports paragraph.ts like so `import { ParagraphBlockComponent } from "./blocks/paragraph";`

Normal compilation works but not the tests.
Here is the karma config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {

config.set({
    basePath: 'src',
    singleRun: true,
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    reporters: ['dots'],
    browsers: ['Firefox'],
    files: [
        'tests/index.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'tests/index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: {
        noInfo: true,
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\_tests.js$/,
                    loaders: ['babel-loader']
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true,
        stats: {
            color: true,
            chunkModules: false,
            modules: false
        }
    }
});

};
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the following to the karma webpack config fixed it for me

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
},
```